# Doors affect villager mechanics in wheat farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I created a wheat farm but the villager is not harvesting, he has a full inventory of the necessary items, but on the video tutorial, someone in the comments said that there must be no doors within 65 blocks of it. If that is true, can I replace all the doors in the area with a non-oak door, such as spruce/birch/etc? Also, is there any way I could place a lot of doors next to the farm to create a village so he starts harvesting?

Comment: Please, edit your question and put the link to the video.

Answer (score 3):

For a villager to harvest, he must:

- **Be a brown-robed villager** (probably your problem)
- Have a farm around him that has either wheat, carrots, or potatoes

Also, the villagers won't throw seeds, only the food.
Check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fnatRPiDl4) video for a farm.

---

Just some more information (if you wanted to build a breeder or something, what you want to do is not clear in the question)

Minecraft declares something a village when:

- There are oak doors
- Those oak doors have a "roof" over them (basically just a block above the door)
- There must be some villagers near (you might want to enclose them)

For more information, check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR9NPbGGqfA) video if you want to build a breeder

Source: My knowledge and [the good o'l Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager)